# Compound error_codes?

Tags: c++, error-code

Say I have a function (please ignore that it's not async for simplicity's sake)

```cpp
http_response http_get(string url, std::error_code& ec);
```

when this function fails, it returns an error through `ec`. So far so good.

Now, say I have another function that uses `http_get` multiple times:

```
int calculate_meaning_of_life(std::error_code& ec) {
    auto r1 = http_get("foo.com", ec);
    if (ec) return 0;
    auto r2 = http_get("bar.com", ec);
    if (ec) return 0;
    return combine(r1, r2);
}
```

But now I have a problem that when the `calculate_meaning_of_life` function fails, I lost the information about which call to `http_get` it was.

Another approach might be for me to define custom error codes, and use them as such:

```
int calculate_meaning_of_life(std::error_code& ec) {
    std::error_code internal_ec;
    auto r1 = http_get("foo.com", internal_ec);
    if (internal_ec) {
        ec = custom_error::failed_at_foo_com;
        return 0;
    }
    auto r2 = http_get("bar.com", internal_ec);
    if (internal_ec) {
        ec = custom_error::failed_at_bar_com;
        return 0;
    }
    return combine(r1, r2);
}
```

But now I'm losing the information about what happened inside `http_get`. Ideally, I would like to preserve all the information, something like this:

```
int calculate_meaning_of_life(std::error_code& ec) {
    std::error_code internal_ec;
    auto r1 = http_get("foo.com", internal_ec);
    if (internal_ec) {
        ec = meaning_error(custom_error::failed_at_foo_com, internal_ec);
        return 0;
    }
    auto r2 = http_get("bar.com", internal_ec);
    if (internal_ec) {
        ec = meaning_error(custom_error::failed_at_bar_com, internal_ec);
        return 0;
    }
    return combine(r1, r2);
}
```

So that when I run it and it fails, I get all the available information. E.g.:

```
std::cerr << ec << "\n"; // Would print: "Failed to retrieve foo.com: operation aborted"
```

To my understanding, `std::error_code` is just an `int` and a pointer to the category structure, so I think there isn't a non-hackish way to make the `int` in the `std::error_code` actually represent a structure.

The only "hackish" way I can now think of to make such compound error code is to abuse that `int` to actually represent more than one value. E.g. by "reserving" first K bits for the custom error code and rest for the "inner" one, or by using the [Cantor's pairing function](http://r6.ca/blog/20190223T161625Z.html) or something similar.

So finally to the question: Is there a recommended way to construct such compound error codes? And/or is there a discussion somewhere on the WWW about such compound error codes? Or maybe there is an alternative?

Comment: If the errors are "exceptional", then throw exceptions instead?

Comment: Thanks, though they often aren't "exceptional", which is the case I'm currently interested in. It's also the case that in our code base we don't use exceptions because with combination with Boost.Asio and coroutines they mess up the address sanitizer (on g++ at least).

Comment: @PeterJankuliak generally error codes are not considered great solution AFAIK. There are two good, yet different strategies of handling exceptional situations - exceptions and "Result Type" which is variant of return type and error message/error object. Both support your needs. And if these situations are not exceptional I would suggest just checks and `if`s, which implies this is expected behaviour

Comment: @PeterJankuliak if i understand correctly, you want to preserve as much information about the context where error occured and error itself  while composing them right?

Comment: @GauravDhiman yes, that's correct

Comment: @bartop yeah, I also think I'll need to use something like Boost.Outcome (the "Result Type") instead. I was hoping to avoid it because integrating it correctly into Asio's coroutine machinery seems like quite a hassle. I'm still curious what other options there are.

Comment: It seems like you are trying to create exceptions by hand. You want to add information about each frame going up the stack. That's exactly what throwing an exception does. I have read that you have disabled exceptions jn your code base, but creating what is basically your own exception will not be much better.

Comment: @n314159 I see your point, although there are other [reasons not to use exceptions](https://ned14.github.io/outcome/videos/), those alone wouldn't be enough for us to decide against them. It's really the combination of the address sanitizer and Asio coroutines that we're not willing to ditch in favor of exceptions.

Comment: Your question made me recall this article by akrzemi: https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2017/09/04/using-error-codes-effectively/

Answer (score 0):

`std::error_code` are not considered a great solution and I would consider that a poor interface. You really should use something that encodes a message as well, eg. change to:

```
int calculate_meaning_of_life(std::system_error& ec) {
```

[`std::system_error`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/system_error/system_error) encodes an `std::error_code` plus a message. It's the responsible of the *thrower*(in this case returned by parameter) to encode enough information to make the exception usefull.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have problems with dynamic allocations per se the following should be a way to do what you want (even if I am not too happy with it)

```cpp
struct my_error {
  std::error_code ec;
  std::string description; // Or whatever is appropriate
}

class my_traceback {
  std::vector<my_error> errors;
  bool unhandled_error = false; // you can let this be, but I think it really adds a bit of safety
public:
  void add_error(my_error&& e) {
    assert(!unhandled_error);
    errors.push_back(std::move(e));
    unhandled_error = true;
  }

  explicit operator bool() const {
    return unhandled_error;
  }

  bool handle_error() {
    return std::exchange(unhandled_error, false);
  }

  my_error& last_error() { // So we can add information to the last error
    return errors.back();
  }

  // Add possibilities to output errors etc.
};
```

Usage in your code would be the following:

```cpp
http_response http_get(string url, my_traceback& tr); 

int calculate_meaning_of_life(my_traceback& tr) {
    auto r1 = http_get("foo.com", tr);
    if (tr.handle_error()) {
      std::error_code ec = tr.last_error().ec; // Probably you want to pass that up the chain? If that is always done, than you can set the ec in my_traceback and remove it from my_error
      tr.add_error({ec, "Failed in Foo"});
      return 0;
    }
    auto r2 = http_get("bar.com", ec);
    if (tr.handle_error()) {
      std::error_code ec = tr.last_error().ec; 
      tr.add_error({ec, "Failed in Bar"});
      return 0;
    }
    return combine(r1, r2);
}
```